# C# .NET Unexpected Typing - Expanded foreach explanation

Tags: c#, .net, types

As I was refactoring some code this morning, I noticed some weird behavior.  I was iterating over a collection of type `A`.  The declaration and usage of the Enumerable were split (I was declaring and defining a variable using some Linq, then iterating over it later via foreach).  However, when I changed the type of the enumerable from `IEnumerable<A>` to `IEnumerable<B>`, I left the foreach as the following where enumerable was of type `IEnumerable<B>`.

```
IEnumerable<B> enumerable = someEnumerableOfB    
foreach(A a in enumerable)
```

Following is a contrived example of the behavior I found:

```
    IEnumerable<IEnumerable> enumerables = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(x => new List<int> { x });
    foreach (StringComparer i in enumerables) //this compiles
    {
        //do something here
    }

    foreach (int i in enumerables) //this doesn't compile
    {
        //do something here
    }

    IEnumerable<StringBuilder> stringBuilders = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(x => new StringBuilder(x.ToString()));
    foreach (FileStream sb in stringBuilders) //this doesn't compile
    {
        //do something here                
    }
```

I was surprised to see the first one compile.  Can someone explain exactly why this works?  I assume it has something to do with the fact that the `IEnumerable` is of an interface, but I can't explain it.

Comment: It does for me, and I'm also using C# 4.0.

Comment: Oh, nevermind. It compiles and fails at runtime. I was testing on LINQPad, and confused the errors :(

Comment: You are correct that the entire code piece won't compile, but the first foreach is compiling for me.

Comment: I fully expect it to fail at runtime, I want to know why it's not corrected at compile time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the algorithm described section §15.8.4. of the [specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf), the compiler will expand the `foreach` into the following:

```
{
    IEnumerator<IEnumerable> e = ((IEnumerable<IEnumerable>)(x)).GetEnumerator(); 
    try
    {
        StringComparer v; 
        while (e.MoveNext())
        {
            v = (StringComparer)(IEnumerable)e.Current; // (*)
            // do something here
        }    
    } 
    finally
    {
        // Dispose of e
    }
}
```

The line I've marked with an asterisk is the reason why it compiles for the first and not for the second. That is a valid cast because you can have a subclass of `StringComparer` that implements `IEnumerable`. Now change it to:

```
v = (int)(IEnumerable)e.Current; // (*)
```

And it doesn't compile, because this is not a valid cast: `int` does not implement `IEnumerable`, and it can't have any subclasses.

Comment: So if C# allowed for multiple-inheritance, would case 3 pass?  It seems like it would.

Comment: @L. Moser: Not exactly case 3 as you have it, because StringBuilder is a sealed class, but yes, that's the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Because the compiler cant know whats in the Enumerable but it knows that it cant be a value type (e.g. int).

foreach (StringComparer i in enumerables) will compile since StringComparer is a reference type and for the compilers sake might just be in enumerables.

Comment: If this is indeed a covariance/contravariance loophole, please explain in more detail.  Specifically, looking at your explanation, I have no way of knowing why the third example doesn't compile.

Comment: Right.  See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5413830/c4-0-int-a-real-subtype-of-object-covariance-ienumerable-and-value-types/5413878#5413878) for more on why the second `foreach` doesn't compile.

Comment: I'm sorry, should have explained in more detail. See the answer of Martinho Fernandes.