# A general way to convert IFoo<T> to IFoo<object>

Tags: c#, .net, generics, covariance, variance

I have an interface:

```
interface IFoo<out T> 
{
   T Get();
}
```

and some instances like `IFoo<int> a`, `IFoo<User> u`, `IFoo<string> s` and etc. There is a `List<IFoo<object>>` used to collect them. But [variance doesn't work for value types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5413830/c4-0-int-a-real-subtype-of-object-covariance-ienumerable-and-value-types), is there a proper way to put them in the list?

Comment: What is `out T` when used as a type parameter?

Comment: @pst - [Covariance and Contravariance](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't look like you need generics for this list, so you can have the interface implement a non-generic interface:

```
interface IFoo<out T> : IFoo { }
```

That way, all of your objects implement the same interface. This may not be a bad idea, since they do have something in common. Now you can simply use a `List<IFoo>`.